# Oracle: How to truncate an table and the tables that references to it

Tags: oracle, truncate

I'm given the task to truncate an Oracle table with millions of records. The problem I had is that there are other tables that reference to it, so it will be necessary to truncate those tables first, but those tables will present the same problem as my initial table. How can I do that recursively?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using? . Have the foreign keys been defined using the `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause?. If yes,Oracle 12c does provide `truncate cascade` option, provided it is defined with on delete.. If not then your only option would be to check all the dependent tables and truncate in the order child->parent->grandparent..

Comment: (Talking about 11gR2): that won't work. You can't TRUNCATE parent table as long as there are enabled foreign keys that point to it (ORA-02266: unique/primary keys in table referenced by enabled foreign keys). First you'll have to DISABLE those constraint, and then perform truncate.